# Swift Core Data Issue (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, xcode6

Here is my code:

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate!)

var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

newUser.setValue("test username", forKey: "firstName")
newUser.setValue("test password", forKey: "lastName")

context.save(nil)

println(newUser)
println("Object Saved.")
```

I've been following this tutorial step for step (with the exception of changing some variable names):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IDfgATVqHw

I think my issue is within:

```
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

"appDel.managedObjectContext" doesn't turn to the green colour as in the video (it only does so if I add an "!" to the end which I think causes my app to then crash)

EDIT: If I do not put the !, the app cannot run/be built.

EDIT 2: App Delegate code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "Dom.Shift_Grabber" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
        }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Shift_Grabber", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
        }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Shift_Grabber.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
        }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
        }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your AppDelegate code? Did you create and initialize the managedObjectContext property there?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I have added the requested code above. I'm fairly new to swift so I may have missed something. :)

Comment: @Mike Taverne Any help?

Comment: Any help Mike? It would really help!

Comment: sorry, I haven't had a chance to look at this further. Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead i was having the same problem as you and i fixed it with this code

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("WebsiteTasks",
        inManagedObjectContext:
        managedContext)
    let en = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    en.setValue(websiteName.text, forKey: "websiteName")
    en.setValue(websiteLink.text, forKey: "websiteLink")
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! It got rid of the error that prevents me from building the app....however the app still crashes when I try to save text. And advice?

Comment: Any help? I still cannot fix the issue!

Comment: did you make sure you changed the "websiteName" and "websiteLink" and the entity name and such to match your app?

Comment: Weird...I just gave the tutorial another shot and it worked.... :/  I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

The ! Shouldn't be crashing your app can you run the app and check where the error is at amd post the line that contains the error?

Comment: I can run the app but it gives me a messed up error code! When I search through the errors, the "appDel.managedObjectContext" is highlighted. NOTE: If I do not put the !, I cannot run the app